# What is the meaning of the sentence shown below?

Tags: meaning

> **He was quiet in his ways**, and his habits were regular.

What is the meaning of 'he was quiet in his ways'.
Could u please explain it for me?

Answer (score 1):

It means *he* never shouted or brought attention to himself either through criticism of others or self promotion or being annoying.